# Question about python string algorithm while using string to load a txt.file

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: The difference between code 1 and code 2]

I am a Python novice.

I know the "line.rstrip()" would print extra space between each line while I using a for loop to open a txt file. But the" line = line.rstrip() " doesn't.
However,I just don't understand the logic behind this difference.  Why line.strip() could print extra space? Could someone tell me the logic behind this difference?

Comment: Please edit your post to contain text, not images.  Links can rot, and images of code can't be copied and tested.

Comment: I did but the system told me that my post has too many codes so it didn't allow me to post. Could you tell me what could I do if I still involve such trouble again?

Comment: Post two lines of your sample text. That’s enough to get the point across.

Comment: Thank you to let me know that, very appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable, so `line.rstrip()` returns a new string, but it isn't assigned to anything, so the string `line` refers to remains unchanged.

`line = line.rstrip()` assigns the new, stripped string returned by the function to the name `line`, preserving the change.

```
>>> line = 'abc   \r\n'
>>> line.rstrip()  # returned value is not assigned a name
'abc'
>>> line           # line still names original, immutable string
'abc   \r\n'
>>> line = line.rstrip()  # line names the new string
>>> line
'abc'
```

Comment: Now, I understand, thank you very much!!!

Comment: Is it possible to write such code: print(line.strip(.upper())?? or since strings are immutable so every time I only can change strings step by step? I can't combine two steps into one step?

Comment: @Philip yes but syntax is `print(line.strip().upper())`.